# SignalR: Use scoped service for IUserIdProvider

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have to make a service / DB call in order to map UserId based on request claims. Normally, I would do that as simply as:

```
public class AuthUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        private IBusinessDependencies Dependencies { get; }

        public AuthUserIdProvider(IBusinessDependencies dependencies)
        {
            Dependencies = dependencies;
        }

        public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            var email = connection.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return Dependencies.EntityServices.UserService.GetUserByEmailCached(email).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Id.ToString();
        }
    }
```

However the `IBusinessDependencies` are scoped because there is bunch of business logic that depends on particular request / session.

Is it possible to register `IUserIdProvider`as scoped instead of singleton? Or maybe there is another better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never personally needed to use `IUserIdProvider`, but I can't see anything that specifically *requires* it to be a singleton. I may have missed something, though. However, I would imagine you must of at least tried registering it as scoped before coming here (hopefully).

Assuming it must be a singleton, then your only option is the service-locator pattern. Instead of injecting `IBusinessDependencies`, inject `IServiceProvider` instead. Then whenever you actually need your `IBusinessDependencies` instance do:

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var dependencies = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBusinessDependencies>();
    // do something with dependencies
}
```

In case it's not obvious, you cannot persist your `IBusinessDependencies` instance to an ivar or something. You will need to pull it out of the service collection each time you need to use it.

Comment: Works great, thank you! Btw: yeah, for some reason the `IUserIdProvider` implementation is required to be provided as singleton